First player tosses 3 and the second player tosses 2 coins. The player who gets more heads wins. Calculate expected value of each player's winning.
First player tosses three and the second player tosses two unbiased coins. The player who tosses more heads wins and gets all five coins. In case the numbers of heads thrown are equal, the game continues with the same five coins. Calculate the expected value of each player's winnings.

$A_i = $ number of heads obtained by $A$ when tosses $2$ coins.
$B_i = $ number of heads obtained by $B$ when tosses $3$ coins.
$$P(E) = P \{ (A_1 \cap B_0) \cup (A_2 \cap B_0) \cup (A_2 \cap B_1) \} =$$
$$=2C_1 \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^3 + \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^2 3C_1 \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^2
= \frac{2}{32} + \frac{1}{32} + \frac{3}{32}$$
$F= \{ \text{A & B tie a particular game} \}$ then $P(F) = P \{ (A_0 \cap B_0) \cup (A_1 \cap B_1) \cup (A_2 \cap B_2) \}= \frac{5}{16}$
$P ( \text{A finally wins the game} ) =P( \text{E or FE or FFE or ...}) = \frac{3}{11}$
Therefore:
$P ( \text{B finally wins the game} ) = 1 - \frac{3}{11} = \frac{8}{11}$
Is that correct?

Clarication requested: " In case the numbers of heads thrown are equal, the game continues." : Continues how?  Does this mean that after 1st player tosses 3, 2nd player tosses 2, and they happen to be tied, they go into a (fair) sudden depth, where each player tosses 1, and then if no one is ahead, they again each toss one, and so forth?  If not, exactly which ties are resolved, and how are they resolved?

With the understanding that ties just restart the game, I agree with your result.

Yes, the tie just restarts the game. Is my line of thinking correct (not just the result)? @lulu

Correct, but maybe slightly inefficient.  Since the game eventually terminates with probability $1$, we can just compute the probability that $B$ wins a particular round and divide that by the probability that the game ends on a particular round.  I think that saves you a couple steps.

Ok, that's smart. Thank you!

The last round of the game is the first non-tied round, so the probability that a player wins the game equals: the probability that the player wins a round given that it is a non-tied round.

It is Correct.
This is a Solution verification , hence I am going to give Alternate Solution , which will verify the given Solution while giving more Intuition.
Alternate Solution :
Let $1$ be heads & $0$ be tails.
Let $xxx:yy$ indicate the 3 tosses by $A$ & then the 2 tosses by $B$.
$A$ wins in these $16$ Cases :
$100:00$ , $010:00$ , $001:00$
$110:00$ , $110:10$ , $110:01$ , $101:00$ , $101:10$ , $101:01$ , $011:00$ , $011:10$ , $011:01$
$111:00$ , $111:10$ , $111:01$ , $111:11$
$B$ wins in these $6$ Cases :
$000:10$ , $000:01$ , $000:11$
$100:11$ , $010:11$ , $001:11$
Overall cases that either $A$ or $B$ win : $22$ (the other $10$ Cases will make the game continue)
When game continues with probability $X=1-A-B$ , the remaining probability will eventually get added to $A$ or to $B$ proportionally , hence we can conclude that $A$ or $B$ will not vary.
Probability that $A$ wins : $16/22=8/11$
